# Populate list or tuple from callable or lambda in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples, callable

This is a problem I've come across a lot lately. Google doesn't seem to have an answer so I bring it to the good people of stack overflow.

I am looking for a simple way to populate a list with the output of a function. Something like this:

```
fill(random.random(), 3) #=> [0.04095623, 0.39761869, 0.46227642]
```

Here are other ways I've found to do this. But I'm not really happy with them, as they seem inefficient.

```
results = []
for x in xrange(3): results.append(random.random())
#results => [0.04095623, 0.39761869, 0.46227642]
```

and

```
map(lambda x: random.random(), [None] * 3)
#=> [0.04095623, 0.39761869, 0.46227642]
```

Suggestions?

---

Thanks for all the answers. I knew there was a more python-esque way.

And to the efficiency questions...

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.1+
$ python -m timeit "import random" "map(lambda x: random.random(), [None] * 3)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.65 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "import random" "results = []" "for x in xrange(3): results.append(random.random())"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "import random" "[random.random() for x in xrange(3)]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 usec per loop
```

Comment: `map` and `filter` are useless if know list comprehensions...

Comment: "as they seem inefficient"?  What have you measured with `timeit`?

Comment: In response to the timeit measurements: What you're measuring is the initial overhead. **All algorithms are fast for n=3**. Try 300 or 3000 to get a better picture of the performance. Also note that a good Python implementation (such as PyPy) may inline all variants and execute the same code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about a [**list comprehension**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

```
[random.random() for x in xrange(3)]
```

Also, in many cases, you need the values just once. In these cases, a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) which computes the values just-in-time and does not require a memory allocation is preferable:

```
results = (random.random() for x in xrange(3))
for r in results:
   ...
# results is "used up" now.
# We could have used results_list = list(results) to convert the generator
```

By the way, in Python 3.x, `xrange` has been replaced by `range`. In Python 2.x, `range` allocates the memory and calculates all values beforehand (like a list comprehension), whereas `xrange` calculates the values just-in-time and does not allocate memory (it's a generator).

Answer (score 2):

why do you think they are inefficient?

There is another way to do it,a list-comprehension

```
listt= [random.random() for i in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   list =  [random.random() for i in xrange(3)]
   list =  [random.random() for i in [0]*3]
   list =  [i() for i in [random.random]*3]
```

Or :

```
  fill =lambda f,n: [f() for i in xrange(n)]
  fill(random.random , 3 ) #=> [0.04095623, 0.39761869, 0.46227642]
```

Answer (score 0):

something more generic...

```
from random import random

fill = lambda func, num: [func() for x in xrange(num)]
# for generating tuples:
fill = lambda func, num: (func() for x in xrange(num))


# then just call:
fill(random, 4)
# or...
fill(lambda : 1+2*random(), 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension is probably clearest, but for the `itertools` afficionado:

```
>>> list(itertools.islice(iter(random.random, None), 3))
[0.42565379345946064, 0.41754360645917354, 0.797286438646947]
```

A quick check with `timeit` shows that the itertools version is ever so slightly faster for more than 10 items, but still go with whatever seems clearest to you:

```
C:\Python32>python lib\timeit.py -s "import random, itertools" "list(itertools.islice(iter(random.random, None), 10))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.93 usec per loop

C:\Python32>python lib\timeit.py -s "import random, itertools" "[random.random() for _ in range(10)]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.19 usec per loop
```